# Is anything wrong with perl's s/../../e?

Tags: regex, perl, security

I was searching for the *Perl* equivalent of python's `re.sub`, in which according to the documentation **repl can be either a string or a callable**.

I eventually found out about the `e` modifier of the perl `s//` function, which would allow me to do things like:

```
my $n = 1;
sub repl {
    return $_[0] x $n ++;
}
my $hw = "hello world";
$hw =~ s/(l)/repl $1/eg;
say $hw;
```

And obtain `helllo worllld`.

I found it a bit suspicious on the security standpoint. I assumed that *Mallory* has control on the `$hw` string and I'm not convinced on the safety of this method, although I was not able to find any possible exploitation.

For sure there's something inherently wrong with the `/ee` modifier: search for the word "vendetta" in [this thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=745900) to get a clue. The double-`e`  lets me think that the evaluated expression (in this case `repl $1`) corresponds to an implicit `eval('repl $1')`.

Is this the case?

### Example of possible issue

- let `$hw = "foo lish"`;
- let the searched pattern be `/(f.*h)/` (which matches the whole `foo lish`);

We clearly have `repl("foo lish")` called, but you could wonder if `repl foo lish` is going to be evaluated. It's a bit ambiguous. This is *not* a problem, but my question is about possible pitfalls whith similar patterns.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Which case? What is your exact question? If you are asking: can i shoot my leg off with it, then I think you can, surely.

Comment: Reguarding your update, `$hw =~ s/(f.*h)/repl $1/e` evaluates (executes) `repl $1` (safe), whereas `$hw =~ s/(f.*h)/repl $1/ee` evaluates (executes) `eval "repl $1"` (not safe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't cause any data to become code. It simply tells Perl to treat part of the .pl file as Perl code. As such, it doesn't introduce any security issues.

If the substitution operator was a function, then

```
s/pat/repl/     ⇒  substitute($_, qr/pat/, sub { qq/repl/ })
s/pat/repl()/e  ⇒  substitute($_, qr/pat/, sub { repl() })
```

And that's obviously perfectly alright.

---

Further proof is that everything one can do with `/e` can do easily be done without.

```
s/pat/repl()/e
```

is similar to

```
s/pat/${\( repl() )/
```

---

`/ee`, on the other hand, could be a security issue. Data can become code.

```
s/pat/repl/ee
```

is similar to

```
s/pat/eval "repl"/e
```

The problem comes with the replacement pattern interpolates<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
$ echo 'print "0wn3d\n";' | perl -e'$_ = <>; s/(.*)/$1/ee'
0wn3d
```

I never use `/ee` since it obscures the fact that you used `eval EXPR`.

---

1. There's no reason to use `/ee` if the replacement expression doesn't interpolate.